# Unable to discard the first two columns of a table while scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I've created a macro in vba using xmlhttp request to parse some tabular data from a webpage. I can get the whole content of that table when I try my below script. However, my intention is to get the content from the column `Card#` to the rest. The bottom line is I wanna get rid of the first two columns `Image` and `Spec#`.

[website link](https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/2018-topps-now/publishedset/271273)

> ***How can I get the tabular content except for the first two columns?***

This is my try so far:

```
Sub GetTable()
    Dim S$, c&, R&, elem As Object, tRow As Object

    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "GET", "https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/2018-topps-now/publishedset/271273", False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S
        For Each elem In .getElementsByTagName("table")(0).Rows
            For Each tRow In elem.Cells
                c = c + 1: Cells(R + 1, c) = tRow.innerText
            Next tRow
            c = 0: R = R + 1
        Next elem
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to include before executing the script:

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simplest to test the value of c being > 3 and adjust the output c for -3

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim S$, c&, R&, elem As Object, tRow As Object

    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "GET", "https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/2018-topps-now/publishedset/271273", False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S
        For Each elem In .getElementsByTagName("table")(0).rows
            For Each tRow In elem.Cells
                c = c + 1
                If c > 3 Then Activesheet.Cells(R + 1, c - 3) = tRow.innerText
            Next tRow
            c = 0: R = R + 1
        Next elem
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the problem seems to be bigger but the solution is way simpler. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah... and even within css for selectors 3 (though providing list to :not suggested for selectors 4) , using a browser, I suspect you would have something hideous like:   tr th:not(:nth-of-type(1))th:not(:nth-of-type(2))th:not(:nth-of-type(3)), td:not(:nth-of-type(1))td:not(:nth-of-type(2))td:not(:nth-of-type(3))      or even tr th:not(.control)th:not(:nth-of-type(2))th:not(:nth-of-type(3)), td:not(.control)td:not(:nth-of-type(2))td:not(:nth-of-type(3))

Comment: But it doesn't seem to be working with a different link from the same set like [this one](https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/1878-forbes-co-baseball-comics-h804-6/publishedset/285647) @QHarr. When I try using your suggested hardcoded approach, I get the data from `Spec#` instead of `Card#`.

Comment: they have different overall column counts. Now you would need to look at a few more pages to decide if a more flexible approach is required. The new link has an additional column and so the number shifts from > 3 to >4 Maybe it is something as simple as getting the th count and substracting 5, may be needs more evolved logic. Let me know.

Comment: Only this two types of links are there @QHarr. Thanks.